# how to get Hash table Arraylist to other intent?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashtable

I have hashtbles in array list.

```
 List<Hashtable<String, String>> info = new ArrayList<Hashtable<String, String>>();


 Hashtable<String, String> hm = new Hashtable<String, String>();
// Put elements to the map

hm.put("Read_Flag", s1);
hm.put("sms_received_id", s2);
hm.put("Sender_Id", s3);
hm.put("Sender_Name", s4);
hm.put("Patient_Name", s5);
hm.put("Received_Date", s6);
hm.put("Received_Text", s7);
hm.put("Received_Text_Full", s8);
hm.put("AttachmentFlag", s9);

// Get a set of the entries
Set<?> set = hm.entrySet();
// Get an iterator
Iterator<?> it = set.iterator();
// Display elements
while(it.hasNext()) {
Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)it.next();
 // System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
 // System.out.println(me.getValue());
}
//System.out.println(hm);

info.add(hm);
```

here info contains my hashtables. how can i get this "info" object into other class/intent?

Thank You...

Comment: It might be just me but I don't get what you're asking for. Maybe an example or more explanation would help.

Comment: not sure what you mean? would you please make it simpler.

Comment: how can i get this "info" object in other class?

Comment: @HaPPy use Serializable or Parcelable.

Comment: @LalitPoptani please give me a example code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a class that extends `Serializable` with `getter` `setter` for the `List<Hashtable<String, String>> list`

**Custom.java**

```
public class Custom implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4466821913603037341L;
    private List<Hashtable<String, String>> list;


    public List<Hashtable<String, String>> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Hashtable<String, String>> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

**To pass to next Activity.**

```
List<Hashtable<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Hashtable<String,String>>();

Custom custom = new Custom();
custom.setList(list);
intent.putExtra("myobj", custom);
```

**To retrieve in next Activity**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Custom custom = (Custom) intent.getSerializableExtra("myobj");
List<Hashtable<String, String>> list = custom.getList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Hashtable<String, String>> info = new ArrayList<Hashtable<String, String>>(); 
String[] selItemArray = new String[info .size()];
            //copy your List of Hashtable Strings into the Array ,and then pass it in your intent
            // ....
            Intent intent = new Intent(InfoClass.this, AnotherClass.class);
            intent.putExtra("info_array", selItemArray);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

**type of arraylist**

```
putIntegerArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<Integer> value)

        putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)

        putStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<String> value)

        putCharSequenceArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<CharSequence> value)

    Then you can read from you next activity by replacing put with get with key string as argument,eg

myIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("key");
```

**Array :**

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray(key, new String[]{value1, value2});
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(b);



In order to read:

Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

Hope this will help you.

Refer : [Passing a list of objects between Activities](http://androidideasblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/passing-list-of-objects-between.html)

Comment: how can i get this in other class?

Comment: it sounds good but i dont want array, i want Arraylist which has hash tables. how to do that?

Comment: you will need to implement Parcelable interface and override some functions to serialize/de-serialize the object

Comment: http://androidideasblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/passing-list-of-objects-between.html

Answer (score 1):

Convert your Hashtables to Bundles, and pass the Bundles using intent.putExtra()
here 's the example

Intent i = new Intent(this,yourclass.class);

i.putExtra("info",info);

and you can get the values in other intent

Bundle extra=getIntent().getExtras();

extra.geStrinf("info");

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Hashtables to Bundles, and pass the Bundles using intent.putExtra()