# How to save the ListView in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState), so i can restore it back in Android?

Tags: android, orientation

The list is pulled from a remote feed over the web, so I was trying to
prevent having to reload the listview via another web pull

Basically I just want the application to save everything and then
restore itself when the user changes orientation, instead of having to
make another full call back data source.
and what i have to write in onSaveInstanceState Method.

What i have to do for plz help me so i can proceed ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to save ListView, you just had to store the data with which you are populating your ListView. [`Here`](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/09/onsaveinstancestate-and.html) is a simple example for the same. Another one you can have is [`this one`](http://alltechsolution.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/savedinstance-onsaveinstancestate-onrestoreinstancestate/).

Comment: I have ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList; when i try doing this it give me an error protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  
  
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  
  outState.putStringArrayList("key",myList );
 }
SO what can i do now ?

Comment: You can use Serializable in that case check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725699/how-to-get-hash-table-arraylist-to-other-intent

Comment: it works fine but their is one more issue in that . when i try to change orientation from landscape to portrait and vice-versa it takes only portrait view and all my aligment in list view get disturbed. So can u suggest me what can i do ?

Comment: This is a different question now you should post another question for this on StackOverflow.

Comment: can u tell me when i save ArrayList in onSaveInstanceState and when i retrive that ArrayList in onRestoreInstanceState can i redraw the List by using that ArrayList

Comment: im not getting proper result dear. So what can i do now ?

Answer (score 1):

Its really simple.
For orientation change you can preserve your activity's data even after the orientation of the screen has changed from portrait to landscape and vice-versa.


You need to make a separate layout xml for the landscape orientation keeping all the elements same (no of views and their ids) as they were in the portrait layout xml.
Place this xml in the folder named "lauout-land" in the "res" folder of the app and give it the same name as that of its counterpart in the "layout" folder.
So whenever their will be a config change the android will inflate this layout xml instead of the one for the portrait mode and vice-versa.
**Edditted Section**
Also if you wanna save something before the orientation changes (I relly dont know why you need this), you can do this 
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
.....
.....
Save anything you wanna save like text of any edit text 
 any arraylist
....
.....
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
....
Now set the saved data to any where you want.
    }
Also if your list is getting reset aftre the orientation change then also your array containing the data must be still there if your activity is not killed.
Set the adapter for your list again.
Resting my suggestions after this.

Comment: I know that but i want to store the data of activity . So when the orientation change it will display same data in that orientation .

Comment: it will retain the same data, as there is no data loss in orientation change of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your list view must be backed by some kind of list may array list, collection etc. You can pass that list to android and ask it to store that object for you while your activity dies and is reborn. The way to do it is using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`. Check the android docs. It's fairly straightforward.

Comment: Can u plz give me an small sample code for that and also for get that data back and display the same List in another orientation.

Comment: [This method is deprecated.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance())

Comment: Yes it's deprecated. However, if you're targeting anything lower than android 4.0, we have only this option available.