# Anchor tag hyperlink to application inner activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm getting anchor tag from database like below. displaying using TextView

```
Click here <a href='http://example.com/202'>information</a>
```

till now it is fine i'm displayng it using `(Html.fromHtml(PostInfo)`. 
Now my question is when i click on this anchor tag it is opening browser to display page but i've that page in my application activity.  what i need is i want to change that anchor tag url to redirect my application activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Open Browser Within Your Application

Create a new Activity which have a web view and pass the URL to that Activity's web view when you click on anchor tag.

Comment: How can i write intent action for particular portion of TextView... Click here <a href='http://example.com/202'>information</a> in this text i need onclick action only for information text not for click here.

Comment: as you say you get the anchor tag value from DB.So Fetch the URL Value(http://example.com/202) from this Anchor Tag and pass and get to the next Activity as i suggest here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725699/how-to-get-hash-table-arraylist-to-other-intent/8725802#8725802

Comment: yes you are right. but you will get action for whole TextView content, i need it only for information text not for click here text.

Comment: Try it with your code TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());