# how to receive string[][] from sendBroadcast

Tags: android, string, broadcastreceiver

I want to receive a `string[][]` from sendBroadcast but failed.
first, i set up a sendBroadcast:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("json_info");
        intent.putExtra("routeshout", result);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

in which result is a `string[][]`

and there:

```
            @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[][] str_result = intent.getStringArrayExtra("routeshout");
            result.setText(str_result[0]);
            Log.d(TAG,"onReceive: "+str_result[1]);
        }

    };
```

but I can get `string[][]` by applying `String[][] str_result = intent.getStringArrayExtra("routeshout");`

any suggestion???

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following..

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String[][] str_result = (String[][])extras.get("routeshout");
```

I should note that I am not sure if it is possible to pass a jagged array through the bundle but since it is only storing strings I imagine it should work.

Comment: it works fine for"Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();"
but when "String[][] str_result = (String[][])extras.get("routeshout");"  i got shutdown and "03-26 04:53:04.490: E/AndroidRuntime(4460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
"

Comment: @Hao Well that is the case I was speaking to; if you want a complex type to be passed through your bundle then it needs to extend Serializable or Parcelable depending on the level of efficiency and control required. The platform has provided this functionality for you on certain simple types (string arrays, value types, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a class that extends `Serializable` and getter setter for your `String[][]` then use the getter setter to set and pass it to next intent using putExtra and retrieve using    `intent.getSerializableExtra()`. [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725699/how-to-get-hash-table-arraylist-to-other-intent/8726458#8726458) is an example for the same, just in place of List use your `String[][]`.

Comment: @Hao: if this helped you, please consider *upvoting* it and *accepting* this answer (by ticking it).