# android fill array string dynamical

Tags: java, android

in my android i have an textview wit auto complete function like this:

```
String [] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
   "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
};

final AutoCompleteTextView editTextCountries = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextCountries);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
editTextCountries.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this works fine.

now i would like to set the countries dynamically.
one activity before i give the countries with an intent and get this countries in the class with the textview like this:

```
String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
      getIntent().getExtras().getString("countries")
};
```

Log.e of getIntent().getExtras().getString("countries"):

> "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"

Same like:

```
String [] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
   "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
};
```

but the auto complete doesn't work like this.
any ideas?

Comment: You do `getIntent().getExtras().getString()`, it's only **one** string and so you create an array with only one element

Comment: mmmmh, okay how can i fill the array with my intent string, to make more than one element?

Comment: @SpecialFighter why are your strings being grouped to begin with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ActivityA:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB);
String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
    "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
};

intent.putExtra("countries", COUNTRIES);
startActivity(intent);
```

In ActivityB:

```
public void onCreate() {
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String[] countries = intent.getStringArrayExtra("COUNTRIES");
}
```

**OR**

In ActivityA:

```
String countries = "Belgium,France,Italy,Germany,Spain";

Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB);

intent.putExtra("countries", countries);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity B:

```
public void onCreate() {
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String[] countries = intent.getExtras().getString("countries").split(",");
}
```

Comment: COUNTRIES = new String[] {getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("COUNTRIES")}; than i get an error: Required String, Found String[]

Comment: Copy this code exactly as it is. It is working fine for me.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept is as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Here `getIntent().getExtras().getString("countries")` returns string so the table will contain one field.

You can pass table in intent like this [how to get Hash table Arraylist to other intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725699/how-to-get-hash-table-arraylist-to-other-intent)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and closest matching answer to the approach specified in your question would be:

Set your string value to: (Delimited)

```
Belgium|France|Italy|Germany|Spain
```

and get the values into your string array using split:

```
String[] countries = getIntent().getExtras().getString("countries").split("|");
```